# Which numerical scheme should be used?

Tags: pde, nonlinear-equations

Trying to find a way to solve exponentially nonlinear elliptic equation with complex source term i manage to know about such schemes like Godunov, Lax-Friedrich, MUSCL. I still seraching for literature about them.

The main question is could this schemes do something with
$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(ce^{\varphi_n-\varphi_c}\dfrac{\partial\varphi_n}{\partial x}\right) = R$$

This schemes traditionally for parabolic/hyperbolic equation, but i could add some time derivative (i erase it because i need stationary solution). Or it is possible to use them with elliptic one? (why not)

I also know that it could possible if only the scheme with it initial condition will be stable. For example, MUSCL scheme deal with discontinueties, large gradient etc. (from Wiki)

Is it possible when $ce^{\varphi_n-\varphi_c}$ change very fast (1e18 in a small area)? Could you adviced me some literature?

P.S. sorry for my english, i working on it.

Comment: I almost trying some simple aproaches which i know. Newton linearization, Pikard iteration (with FVM). This approach working good for a much more lover exponenta.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is well-posed and is well conditioned?

Comment: The problem is well posed because it has unique solution, its solution a continuous and it exist (i assume that because it modeling some physics and it almost solved in some commercial soft, unfornetly i couldnt prof its existance now ). But the matrixes i recieve till now (by using Pikard etc) is ill conditioned because of changing of coefficient from 1e18 till 1.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic only has 16 digits. Coefficients that vary by 18 orders of magnitude on small scales can not be resolved computationally -- for all practical purposes, your coefficient is zero in some areas, and you will have to model it as such.

Comment: It is very interesting. Should i use more digits for calculation (there is such libreries). Or your words about zero coefficients meant to use some specific methods?
For example, there is Tridiagonal matrix algorithm which solves a system of algebraic equations  line by line ... and if discretization on area with rapid change will be dense it could erase such a problem?

Comment: The schemes you mention (Godunov, Lax-Friedrichs, MUSCL) are for hyperbolic problems, not elliptic problems.  It seems to me that you're very confused and it's unlikely that we can help.  Do you have a mentor you can speak to?

Comment: in books this shcemes propose for u'_t + f_x(u) = 0 and its quate closer to my problem. I coould add some time (actually i erase time because i need stationary solution) and equation become parabolic/hyperbolic - i cant sanse the differense. Unfortunatly i couldnt ask anyone about such problem in mu university.

Comment: Actually i know about this schemes from "A beginners course in finite volume approximation of scalar conservation law". Is there any methods for elliptic equations? or for something that become from elliptic equation with added time?

Comment: I got it, adding time to my equation make it parabolic because first derivative in time and second in space. Methods which i mentioned before applied to equation wgich first in time and first in space probably (nobody in the text say it hyperbolic equations)

Comment: Yep, this schemes for hyperbolic. Thanks for your comment, i really misunderstand this part (still, it was interesting to read about them)